# Can Helm test be used to run separate suites?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Is it possible to do the following,(and has anyone been successful)

Having 2 jobs as separate files:

```
helm/tree/master/general/templates/tests/job1.yaml
helm/tree/master/general/templates/tests/job2.yaml
```

Call either file using e.g.

```
 helm test general/job1.yaml -n ENV
```

Instead of

```
 helm test general -n ENV
```

Or is it limited to all files in that folder being run sequentially?

Comment: Pingback: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63011453/how-to-choose-which-test-suite-to-run-on-my-helm-release is a more general question, where an answer here would be one solution.