# How to choose which test suite to run on my helm release

Tags: testing, kubernetes, continuous-integration, kubernetes-helm

I want to run different test suites on my helm release in different (partly manual) CI jobs.

How do I best execute these test suites from a CI job?

---

Details:

With a single test suite, `helm test` is very helpful. But how can I easily tell `helm test` which test suite to execute?

Currently, I have only two test suites `A` and `B` and an environment variable `SUITE` I inject via helm install. The test job decides based on the value of `SUITE` which test suite to execute. But this injection is complex and I would like to have the possibility to execute multiple test suites sequentially or concurrently.

Thus I created two helm charts `A.yaml` and `B.yaml`. Can I somehow call `helm test` with a specific helm chart, e.g. `helm test general/A.yaml` (see [Can Helm test be used to run separate suites?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60818255/750378))?

If not, what is the best approach? Using `deployment-A` and `deployment-B` with instances 0 and scale a deployment to 1 when we want to execute it? How do I then communicate the (un-)successful test execution (and log output) back to CI (gitlab in my case)?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to choose test cases using `helm test --filter name=value` - see the [helm docs](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_test/).

Note that `name` here refers to the the `metadata.name` in the helm chart. It's possible to use other attributes set in the helm chart.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is not currently supported in helm (check out [this opened issue](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/5647) on github).

What you can do instead is create separate chart folder with one of the tests in it or check out [Octopus](https://github.com/kyma-incubator/octopus). It was created to replace `helm test` with additional functionalities and one of them is selective testing.